# Laravel email update validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have problem updating my email. `id`, `prn`, `rfid_number` works fine. But in email. I got a problem. Here's my validation:

```js
$validate = $request -> validate([
  'id' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,id,'.$user -> id,
  'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user -> email,
  'prn' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,prn,'.$user -> prn,
  'rfid_number' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,rfid_number,'.$user -> rfid_number
]);
```

Entering email which is not in the database works fine. But when I enter the email of the existing model. "The email has already been taken." shows

Comment: That's because you are validating `uniqueness`, so if the email exists, it will show validation error

Comment: What do you mean by existing model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using this `request` for update operation, then you need to remove the `unique:users,email` portion from your validation test. This is because if the email exists in the `users` table (as it will for the existing users), validation will throw some error. You can make it unique by appending the user id.

```
$validate = $request -> validate([
  'id' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,id',
  'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$user->id
  'prn' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,prn,'.$user -> prn,
  'rfid_number' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,rfid_number,'.$user -> rfid_number
]);
```

If this request for update only, you do not need to check the uniqueness of the `id` column. Because in a update request, `id` will be a unique, and therefore validation will fail. On the other hand, if `id` does not exist, update operation will fail anyway.

Comment: How about my `id`, `prn` and `rfid_number`? Why it works fine?

Comment: Because, you were unneccesarily concatenating `$user -> id` with your id. So, with that concatenation, it was becoming unique. I updated my answer above. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the user id to the validator to skip the email validation for the user whose email is being updated.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,'.$user->id
```

[Read More](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: It works! But why my `id`, `prn`, and `rfid_number` works even if I did not use `'prn' => 'required|numeric|unique:users,prn,'.$user->id`?

Comment: You are already passing the `id`,`prn` and `rfid_number` to the validator. So it will check the validation and return true or false accordingly. But for email address, you need to pass the user id to get the user instance and skip the validation. Sorry, I am not able to make you understand properly.